# Add timeout argument to python's Queue.join()

Tags: python, queue, timeout

I want to be able to join() the Queue class but timeouting after some time if the call hasn't returned yet.
What is the best way to do it? Is it possible to do it by subclassing queue\using metaclass?

Comment: You'd ensure that all worker thread end with task_done()

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Subclassing `Queue` is probably the best way. Something like this should work (untested):

```
def join_with_timeout(self, timeout):
    self.all_tasks_done.acquire()
    try:
        endtime = time() + timeout
        while self.unfinished_tasks:
            remaining = endtime - time()
            if remaining <= 0.0:
                raise NotFinished
            self.all_tasks_done.wait(remaining)
    finally:
        self.all_tasks_done.release()
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you get info about all_task_done? I looked in http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#module-Queue but I don't see any mention of that memeber...

Comment: You can read the source code for Queue. It has a `timeout` parameter implemented for `put` and `get`, it was easy enough to extend `join` to use a similar approach.

Comment: Any idea why `all_tasks_done` is not documented? This may mean that this method could be changed/broken in any release.

Comment: how is this implemented? do you call q.join_with_timeout instead of q.join()?

Answer (score 18):

The *join()* method is all about waiting for all the tasks to be done.  If you don't care whether the tasks have actually finished, you can periodically poll the unfinished task count:

```
stop = time() + timeout
while q.unfinished_tasks and time() < stop:
    sleep(1)
```

This loop will exist either when the tasks are done or when the timeout period has elapsed.

Raymond

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should ensure that all your working threads in the queue exit with `task_done()`

To implement a timeout functionality with `Queue`, you can wrap the Queue's code in a Thread and add a timeout for this Thread using `Thread.join([timeout])`

**untested example to outline what I suggest**

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

def queuefunc():
    q = Queue()
    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    for item in source():
        q.put(item)

    q.join()       # block until all tasks are done

t = Thread(target=queuefunc)
t.start()
t.join(100) # timeout applies here
```

Comment: `t.join(100)` will be a timeout for the whole job. That wouldn't work for my use case, where I fill the queue over several hours and only call `q.join()` after I am done loading sources. Then I should have a much shorter timeout to catch the cases where, for whatever reason (including bugs), the workers fail to call `q.get()` enough times or `q.task_done()` equally many times.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to implement the accepted answer, it seems that `all_tasks_done` is not defined anymore. A quick solution is to use the `timeout` of the `wait()` function called in `JoinableQueue.join`.

For example overriding the `join` function in a subclass of `JoinableQueue` will add a 15s timeout on the waiting operation :

```
def join(self):
    with self._cond:
        if not self._unfinished_tasks._semlock._is_zero():
            self._cond.wait(15)
```

Comment: how this is implemented ??

Comment: @free_123 which part ? the code in the answer should be put in a new class inheriting from JoinableQueue, to define a new type of Queue that you should use in your code.